# how to make an alert pop up before my script

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm new to js and I was working on something where this thing makes a bunch of new tabs, but when the code is run, the alert pops up when each tab is opened and on each individual tab.
here's the code

```
<script>
    alert('something')
    setInterval(function() {
        var w = window.open();
     w.document.write(document.documentElement.outerHTML||document.document 
    Element.innerHTML);
      }, );
</script>
```

pls be nice I'm new

Comment: what is the exact behavior you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want there to be an alert, then have my code run. my code makes some tabs instantly, but that doesn't work with the alert bc the alert comes up on each tab, and I need it to come up on only the first tabe that the code is on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Hi there");
  
  window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```